# How to pass array data from controller to blade in Laravel

Tags: php

I want to pass variable $matches5 with index number 1 to my view, this is getData function in my controller

```
public function getData($txt){
    if (preg_match("/berkedudukan di\s+(\w*(?:\W*\w)*)\W*selanjutnya disebut sebagai PIHAK\W*KESATU/", $txt, $matches5)) {
    }
    return view('mou', ['inputMitra' => $matches5[1]]);
}
```

Then, i want put $matches5 to value in form

```
<form method="GET" action="/upload" name="getForm">
    <div class="form-group mt-5">
        <label for="inputMitra">Mitra Kerjasama</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMitra" placeholder="Mitra Kerjasama" value="{{ $inputMitra }}">
```

Why this code get error undefined variable for $inputMitra?

Comment: Hi Rangaa, welcome to Stack Overflow :)
What do you get if you var_dump($matches5) ?

Comment: Learn to Debug. so right before the `return` in your function use `dd($matches5[1]);` to see what's being sent to Blade, if that is empty,, go one level up, and `dd($matches5);`